# Scrolling doesn't work when there is UIGestureRecognizer inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following hierarchy : UIScrollView  ->  3 SKView's -> SKScene in each view, and in each scene there are UIGestureRecognizer (pan and tap). now, no matter what i do the scroll doesn't work. The things I tried so  far:

1. Enable user interactions across the hierarchy.
2. cancelsTouchesInView = false ,
3. implement UIGestureRecognizerDelegate (shouldReceive)
4. change UIGestureRecognizer position in he hierarchy.

Is there any way to user a UIGestureRecognizer inside a UIScrollView  which will both of the respond  or am i forced to manually handle all touches ?  didn't didn't any clues in the official documentation.

Comment: try the `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` method. For more details refer to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/allowing_the_simultaneous_recognition_of_multiple_gestures

Comment: it actually kind of working, thanks ! all i need to decide  is if  i want to disable and enable  ( to pan if an object is touched , scroll otherwise) or sort reverse the scrolling , so it web sync with the direction of the pan.